# table and caption distance

Tags: tables, spacing, captions, amsbook

I am quite new to Latex, and I was wondering, if there is way to change the distance between the caption and the table. 
If you compile this example you can understand what I mean.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\\hline

\end{tabular}\\
\caption{blah}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Somehow I can't change it so the `ngerman` isn't there, I get an error everytime I try. Maybe because I am using `a4paper`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Great that you included your MWE! However, not all are Germans, could you edit your question to skip German characters and the requirement of the German options?

Comment: Tables usually have the caption on top of the tabular. The space will be just fine then. Are you aware of package siunitx? There is a big difference in *m* and m. Btw. vertical lines are distracting

Comment: Why are they distracting? Aren't the lines used to separate the columns for better readability?

Comment: Concerning units, you might find some interesting remarks over at [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/2588/wie-schreibe-ich-zahlen-mit-einheiten-richtig).

Comment: Can we take this over to the chat? On the top of the page, there is the StackExchangebutton, and from there you can go to chat. This way we do not mess up the commentaries. Or you could just read the documentation of booktabs.

Comment: @Johannes_B [20 rep required for chat](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: @texenthusiast Ups, oh right. OP: Well think about the direction you are reading. Horizontally or vertically with the lines?

Comment: Thanks, I think it helps putting the caption above the table.

Answer (score 5):

Changing the standard lengths `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` seems to have no effect with `amsbook` class.

Anyway you can load the `caption` package

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

and issue (adjust `5pt` to your needs)

```
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=5pt}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\captionsetup[table]{belowskip=5pt}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{blah}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `amsbook` class requires that captions to tables are above the table, while for figures they should be below the figure. You also need no `\centering`, because it's automatically provided.

The class is mainly thought for submissions to the AMS, so it follows the editorial guidelines of the Society.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{blah}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]

\rule{3cm}{2cm}

\caption{blah}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to keep the same look and feel of `amsbook`, but to typeset all captions below the object, here's a patch, based on the fact that the magic number 64 is the one that distinguishes between figures and tables.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}
  {\@tempcnta<64}
  {\@tempcnta<\maxdimen}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{blah}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
\rule{3cm}{2cm}

\caption{blah}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used packages `tabularx` and `float`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper,final,titlepage,openany]{amsbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}‎
‎\usepackage{tabularx}‎‎
‎\usepackage{float}‎
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\\hline
blah & blah & blah & blah \\\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{blah}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```